# jQuery Mobile Panel / jQuery Cookies

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cookies

I am creating a jQuery Mobile site (1.4.2) and using panels.  I have set up a script to open the panel on load if the window width is gt 768.  This works fine with the exception of users that close the panel and want to keep it closed while doing certain tasks, so I am thinking of setting a cookie value when they close the panel and only run the script that opens the panel if the cookie is not set.

For my initial script I have the following and all is well -

```
<script>    
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
   var width = $(window).width();
   if(width > 768) {
      $('##bluebuttonsPanel').panel('open');                  
   }
});
</script>
```

Using the jquery cookie plugin I am setting the cookie like this -

```
<script>
$(document).on('pageinit', function() { 
   if( $('.ui-panel').hasClass('ui-panel-closed') == true ) {
      $.cookie('panel','is-hidden');
   } else {
      $.cookie('panel','is-visible');
   };
});
</script>
```

Where I am confused is trying to change the value of the cookie when they click the tab for the panel, then if the panel cookie value is set to 'is-hidden', not run the initial open script. So I don't know how to change the value of the cookie on click and test for the condition on the open script...

```
$('a#tab').click(function () {
   if ($.cookie('panel', 'is-visible')){ ...?
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!  I hope I am posting this correctly because I haven't posted in a really long time!  TIA!

Comment: Is your application all running within one web page?  If so, you might want to consider global variables as opposed to cookies.  Cookies are generally used to save state between browser sessions as opposed to maintain state within a single browser session.

Comment: Thanks Kolban!  No we are changing pages throughout the application.  So whenever a page refresh or page change occurs, the script that opens the panel runs on each request and reopens the panel.  Form submits are not ajax nor are the page changes. That is what I am trying to reslove!

Comment: I'd love to assist but I'm still not getting the meat of the puzzle.  For example, you have two <script> sections.  Are they in the same page? Maybe if we break the problem down into smaller parts.  Is your question about how to use the jquery.cookie() functions?

Comment: Hi Kolban, you're doing great! I think it is confusing the way that I posted it. It is all on the same page (same HTML head section)... I think what is really giving me trouble is how to toggle the cookie value when the user clicks on the panel tab so that I can set the cookie to 'is-hidden' (initially it will be set to is-visible) and then only run the panel open function if the cookie is not set to 'is-hidden'.  Maybe it would be better to only set the cookie when they close the panel?  I am probably confusing; thank you so much for offering to help me!  I'm  stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked with this problem a while and came up with a solution that seems to be working so far.

I the head of the calling page I am checking to see if a cookie exists named 'panel' with a value of 'is-hidden'.  Only if the window width is greater than 768 and the cookie value is not equal to 'is-hidden' will it open the panel automatically.

```
 $(document).on('pageinit', function(){

          var width = $(window).width();                 
           if(width > 768 && ($.cookie('panel') != 'is-hidden')) {
             $('#bluebuttonsPanel').panel('open'); 
           }

    });
```

In the bottom of the page I am setting the cookie when the user clicks the tab by looking at the current class of the panel when the user clicks the tab - So if the panel is open and the user clicks on the tab, the state of the panel is now closed and the cookie value is set to 'is-hidden.'

```
 $('#tab').click(function () {          
      if( $('.ui-panel').hasClass('ui-panel-open') == true ){    
       $.cookie('panel','is-hidden');

       }

       else {
       $.cookie('panel','is-visible');
      }

   });
```

I only want to remember the cookie value per session so at the end of their session I am clearing the value of the cookie and setting it to 'null.'

```
  $.cookie("panel", null);
```

In this way the use can navigate through the site with the panel closed if desired, without opening it automatically on each request, and it keeps it closed on page load for smaller screens (which is the default behavior).

It is working as expected!  Any improvements and ideas are certainly welcome!